# my app stops working when I put a while loop

Tags: java, freeze

im creating a app with java for making app easyer than coding it but when i started i created two inputs for height and width and a button to create a frame with that informatiion. then i made a while loop to if the number of the height or width changes, change the width and height of the new frame. after that my app stops working and freeze.

i tried to making a jpanel not a jframe or creating a method for that but still freesing.

what do i do to not freeze?

Main.java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Frame();
    }
}
```

Frame.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Frame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    SpinnerNumberModel modelheight;
    JSpinner heightinp;
    SpinnerNumberModel modelwidth;
    JSpinner widthinp;
    JButton newframebutton;
    private int heightdyn;
    private int height;
    private int widthdyn;
    private int width;
    private boolean framerunning= false;
    Frame(){
        //-inputs------------------------------------------------------

        modelheight = new SpinnerNumberModel(500,0,2000,1);
        modelwidth = new SpinnerNumberModel(500,0,2000,1);

        heightinp = new JSpinner(modelheight);
            heightinp.setBounds(25,25,250,50);



        widthinp = new JSpinner(modelwidth);
            widthinp.setBounds(25,100,250,50);

        //--give-value-------------------------------------------------
        heightdyn = (int) heightinp.getValue();
        height = heightdyn;
        widthdyn = (int) widthinp.getValue();
        width = widthdyn;
        //--button-manager---------------------------------------------
        newframebutton = new JButton("New Frame");
        newframebutton.setBounds(25,175,50,50);

        newframebutton.addActionListener(this);






        //--frame-manager----------------------------------------------

        JPanel framepanel = new JPanel();
        framepanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,600));
        framepanel.setLayout(null);

        framepanel.add(heightinp);
        framepanel.add(widthinp);
        framepanel.add(newframebutton);





        this.add(framepanel);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setResizable(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource()==newframebutton){
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            height = heightdyn;
            width = widthdyn;
            framerunning = true;
            frame.setSize(width,height);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
            while (framerunning){
                heightdyn = (int) heightinp.getValue();
                widthdyn = (int) widthinp.getValue();
                if (height != heightdyn || width != widthdyn){
                    frame.setSize(widthdyn,heightdyn);
                    height = heightdyn;
                    width = widthdyn;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't block the event dispatch thread but use a SwingWorker etc. More on this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html

Comment: while(framerunning), and you never update the value of that boolean, it's likely you're just stuck in an endless loop

Comment: @Stultuske okay then what do I do to update the frame and not freeze.

Answer (score 2):

while (framerunning) after setting framerunning=true. Also, you are not modifying framerunning variable inside the while loop. So, the system will go in an infinite loop. So, ultimately your thread will get blocked at that point.